# Show $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}= 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polar-coordinates

When trying to verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations in $z = 0$ for $f(x + i y) = \frac{x y^2 (x + i y)}{x^2 + y^4}$ for $x + i y \ne 0$ and $0$ for $x + i y = 0$, I encountered the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}$$
as I decomposed $\frac{x y^2 (x + i y)}{x^2 + y^4} = \frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2 + y^4} + i \frac{x y^3}{x^2 + y^4} = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$. Then $\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}$.
From plotting I suspect that the limit is zero, however I have't managed to prove it.

It tried using $u := x^2 + y^4$ as $u \to 0$ $\iff$ $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, which yields $| x | \le x^{1/2}$ and $| y | \le u^{1/4}$.
Thus
$$
\left| \frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2} \right|
\overset{\triangle \ne}{\le} \frac{3 | x |^3 | y |^2 + | x | | y |^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}
\le \frac{3 u^{3/2} u^{1/2} + u^{1/2} u ^{6/4}}{u^2}
= 4 \ne 0.
$$
I also tried polar coordinates $x = r \cos(\theta)$, $y = r \sin(\theta)$ with $r > 0$ and $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$:
$$
\frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}
= \frac{3 r^5 \cos(\theta)^3 \sin(\theta)^2 - r^7 \cos(\theta) \sin^6(\theta)}{(r^2 \cos^2(\theta) + r^4 \sin^4(\theta))^2} 
= \frac{3 r \cos(\theta)^3 \sin(\theta)^2 - r^3 \cos(\theta) \sin^6(\theta)}{(\cos^2(\theta) + r^2 \sin^4(\theta))^2} 
$$
But I don't know how to simplify this further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}$ does not exist:

let $h(x,y):=\frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}$ for $(x,y) \ne (0,0).$

Then $h(x,x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $h(y^2,y) \to 1/2$ as $y \to 0.$

Comment: But then how can I show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied if the limit doens't exist?

Comment: 1. the Cauchy - Riemann equations are satisfied at $z=0$. For example: $v_x(0,0)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{v(h,0)-v(0,0)}{h}=0$. Now show that $u_x(0,0)=u_y(0,0)=v_y(0,0)=0.$ 2. we have $ v_x(x,y)= \frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2} $ for $(x,y) \ne (0,0).$ My answer shows that $v_x$ is not continuous at $(0,0).$

Comment: And $v(0, 0) = 0$ as $f(0) = 0$, right?

Comment: Please add the comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It may be interesting to substitute $u = y^2$ and consider the limit at $u \to 0^+$, so we get
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3 x^3 y^2 - x y^6}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}
 = \lim_{(x,u) \to (0,0^+)}\frac{3 x^3 u - x u^3}{(x^2 + u^2)^2}
 = \lim_{(x,u) \to (0,0^+)}\frac{xu(3 x^2 - u^2)}{(x^2 + u^2)^2}
$$
and now polar coordinates really help.

Comment: I then get
$$
\frac{r^2 \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) \left[ 3 r^2 \cos^2(\theta) - r^2 \sin(\theta) \right]}{r^4}
= \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) \left[ 3 \cos^2(\theta) - \sin(\theta) \right]
= \frac{\sin(2\theta) + \sin(4\theta)}{2}
\xrightarrow{\theta \to 0}0,
$$
but doesn't that conflict with the other answer?

Comment: Your limit depends on $ \theta$ !  Not $ \theta \to 0$, but $r \to 0.$